# Creating a Serialiser for a Reverse Generic Relationship

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

Within my Page Serialisers `PageSerializer` shown below, I would like to get the Generic relationship from Collection and
show all Collection Items (which is a many-to-many) nested within PageSerializer.

I want to achieve an output something like this....

```
"results": [
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/page/00c8015e-9b03...",
            "title": "Test Page",
            "collections":
                {
                    "title": "Test Collection",
                    [
                     {
                       "image": "http://www.demo.com/test.png",
                       "video": None
                     },
                      {
                       "image": None,
                       "video": "http://www.demo.com/test.mpeg"
                     }
                    ]
                }

        }
    ]
}
```

This is what I currenrlty have....

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)


class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ("title", )



class Collection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80, help_text="Title of collection")
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.UUIDField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    collection_items = models.ManyToManyField('collections.CollectionItem')


class CollectionItem(models.Model):

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/test')
    video = models.URLField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
```

Becuase the Generic relationship is on the Collection Model **how can this be done in DRF?**

I was thinking of creating a method on the Page model itself which gets the data and adding this to the serializer.

I'm sure there is a better way. I have looked at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#generic-relationships
but it only describes getting the relationship the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [GenericRelation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation) on your Page model for example:

```
class Page(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
     stuff = GenericRelation('app_name_model_here')
```

Then used your nested serializer like this...

```
class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    stuff = YOURColltionserializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ("title", "stuff" )
```

Once you have defined your `YOURColltionserializer` this will work as excepted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your JSON is incorrect, the propher way is something like this:

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/page/00c8015e-9b03...",
         "title":"Test Page",
         "collections":{
            "title":"Test Collection",
            "collection_items":[
               {
                  "image":"http://www.demo.com/test.png",
                  "video":null
               },
               {
                  "image":null,
                  "video":"http://www.demo.com/test.mpeg"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

To achieve this You should define serializer like this:

```
class CollectionItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = CollectionItem
       fields = ['image', 'video']

class CollectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    collection_items = CollectionItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
       model = Collection
       fields = ['title', 'collection_items']

class PageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializes.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    collections = CollectionSerializer(many=true, read_only=True)

    def get_url(self, obj):
        return self.context.request.path_info

class ResultSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    result = PageSerializer(read_only=True)
```

Then in your view:

```
page = Page.objects.get(...)
collections = Collection.objects.filter(...)
result = {
    'title': page.title, 
    'collections':collections
}

serializer = ResultSerializer(
   {'result':result},
    context={'request': request}
}
return Response(serializer.data)
```